# Generate incrementing date strings

Tags: php

I need to generate a string of incrementing dates, something like this:

```
(year, month, day, hour, minute)
2010, 2, 12, 11, 30
2010, 2, 12, 11, 31
etc
```

What would be the best way of doing this? I may want to generate up to 1000 lines like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [date classes](http://php.net/datetime) (note: DateInterval and DatePeriod are only available as of PHP 5.3) to make life easy.

```
$start    = new DateTime('2010-02-12 11:30', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1M'); // 1 minute interval
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, 100); // Run 100 times

foreach ($period as $datetime) {
    // Output like: 2009, 02, 12, 11, 30
    echo $datetime->format("Y, m, d, H, i") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

For a less pretty, but available in older versions of PHP, alternative then see the other suggestions recommending [mktime](http://php.net/mktime).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out PHP's built-in functions: [**`date`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [**`mktime`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).
Used together you can achieve what you want.

As an example to increment the day taken directly from the website.

```
<?php
$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++ ) {
        $startTimeSec = mktime(11, 30 + $i, 0, 2, 12, 2010);
        echo date("Y, m, d, h, i", $startTimeSec) . "\n" . '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
 $tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+$i,date("Y"));
 echo "Tomorrow is ".date("Y m d", $tomorrow);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest that comes to my mind with PHP < 5.3

```
echo '(year, month, day, hour, minute)', PHP_EOL;
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo date('Y, m, d, H, i', strtotime("+$i minute")), PHP_EOL;
}
```