# Date and number - create array

Tags: php, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate incrementing date strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447875/generate-incrementing-date-strings)

I have:

```
$start_date = '2012-09-03';
$number_days = 5;
```

I would like receive array with this dates:

```
$dates = array(
            '2012-09-03',
            '2012-09-04',
            '2012-09-05',
            '2012-09-06',
            '2012-09-07'
 );
```

What is the best way for this?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use, higher or equal to 5.3?

Comment: PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3. This is on two servers

Comment: On which one you will run the script or it does not maters?

Comment: you are supposed to [do research before asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice). How to get a date range or add and subtracts time from a date has been asked and answered dozens of times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start_date = '2012-09-03';
$dates[] = $start_date;
$number_days = 5;
for ($i=1; $i < $number_days; $i++) {
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start_date +$i days"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php
Loop over and add the dates you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
    function get_days($start_date, $max){
        $ts=strtotime($start_date);
        $next_day_interval=24*60*60;
        $arr=array();
            $arr[]=$start_date;
        for($i=1;$i<=$max;$i++){
            $ts += $next_day_interval;
            $arr[]=date('Y-m-d', $ts);
        }

        return $arr;
    }
```

Just wrote it here so there might be some compile time errors but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$start_date = '2012-09-03';
$number_days = 5;

$dates = array();
$TS = strtotime($start_date);
$dates[0] = $start_date;
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $dates[$i] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $TS));
    $TS = strtotime($dates[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're searching for (work also on PHP < 5.3)

```
<?php 
    $start_date = '2012-09-03';
    $number_days = 5;

    $stdate = date(strtotime($start_date));
    $dates = array();
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $number_days ; $i++) {
      $dates[$i] = date('Y-m-d', $stdate) ;
      $stdate += 24*60*60;
    }

    var_dump($dates);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified Code from @vinay to print actual output

```
<?php 
$start_date = '2012-09-03';
$number_days = 5;

$dates = array();
$TS = strtotime($start_date);
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $dates[$i] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $TS));
    $TS = strtotime($dates[$i]);
   echo date('y-m-d',$TS).'<br>';

}
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my ans. As it was neglacting first date '2012-09-03' and it starts from '2012-09-04'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example with PHP 5.3 DateTime and DateInterval. This is clear solution. **Note: PHP 5.2 supports DateTime, but not DateInterval. You may declare it in custom class in PHP 5.2, see here: [DateInterval Definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).**

```
<?php
   $start_date = '2012-09-03';
   $number_days = 5;
   $dt = new DateTime($start_date);

   $dates = array();

   for($i = 0; $i < $number_days; $i++) {
       $dates[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
       $dt->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
   }


   print_r($dates);
?>
```